# t test for stationarity of time series

Tags: hypothesis-testing, t-test, stationarity

How is the t test used for testing the stationarity of time series.
I have tried to search literature which says that if the mean , standard deviation and higher moments of the partitioned time series are not significantly different it can be called a stationary series, but I do not find it enough to perform the quantitative test myself

Comment: What do you think about my answer? Does it answer your question? If so, you may accept it by clicking on the tick mark to the left. Otherwise, you may ask for further clarification. This is [how Cross Validated works](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

You test agaist specific alternatives, e.g. changing mean, changing variance, changing higher moments. For each one, one or more tests exist, and they are not necessary based on the $t$-test. The closest one could be the [augmented Dickey-Fuller test](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/augmented-dickey-fuller/info) with a $t$-statistic following a nonstandard distribution under the null hypothesis of presence of a unit root (a type of nonstationarity in the mean).